# "connect" multiple arrays from json

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I want to replace data I receive from a json-array with text from another json-array to write it in a table (I use datatables).
The first data-set comes from [here](https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/rankings/character/Eigentlich/Aegwynn/EU?zone=11&metric=dps&api_key=73da8e865e0bd8776bbab23f57291755), the second data-set comes from [here](https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/classes?api_key=73da8e865e0bd8776bbab23f57291755)
This is my source code so far:

```
<?php
$charname = $_POST['charname'];
$server = $_POST['server'];
$region = $_POST['region'];

$json = file_get_contents('https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/rankings/character/' . $charname . '/' . $server . '/' . $region . '?zone=11&metric=dps&api_key=73da8e865e0bd8776bbab23f57291755');
$arr = json_decode($json);
$classjson = file_get_contents('https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/classes?api_key=73da8e865e0bd8776bbab23f57291755')
$classarr = json_decode($json);
?>

<table id="table_wcl">
<thead>
    <th>Boss</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Spec</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Percent</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($arr as $newvar) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $newvar->encounter . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $newvar->class . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $newvar->spec . "</td>";
        echo "<td>Rank " . $newvar->rank . " of " . $newvar->outOf . "</td>";
        echo "<td>Top " . substr((($newvar->rank / $newvar->outOf) * 100), 0, 4) . " %</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is: Where I take the `$newvar->class`, I obviously get a number in my table. But I want the program to compare the result from the first json-array with the second json-array, and then take the text from the second one.
In this case: `class 4 = Mage`, `spec 2 = Fire`
The same goes for encounters I get from [here](https://www.warcraftlogs.com:443/v1/zones?api_key=73da8e865e0bd8776bbab23f57291755) (pretty far down, `id: 11`, name `"The Nighthold"`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using the eu.battle.net api instead? also your going to need two loop (maybe 3)  then you can compare compare the values like ($class->id === $newvar->class). You can also create another array and pass only what you need.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Should I use the battle.net api to get class/spec for `charname`? I didn't use the battle.net api yet. In the end isn't it the same like above? When using another api I have multiple datasets and need to connect them somehow. I will try your second advice.

Comment: Looking in dev.battle.net the data does seem to be different, but again, I was just curious and don't really care :-).